# Restart the Django Server after DB change

Tags: django, python-3.x

How can I make the Django server restart everytime I changed something in the database?

So let's say I executed a Model.objects.update() on the DB, how can I make the Django server do a restart automatically?
I use a dropwdown filter and when I update a value from '25' to let's say '22' the dropdown filter still displays '25' until I manually restart the server. How can I change that?

Here is my form. I use django_filters for the Dropdown Filter.

```
class CSVFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    entries = CSV5.objects.values_list('gebaeudebereich', flat = True).distinct()
    gebaeudebereich_auswahl = [(e, e) for e in entries]
    gebaeudebereich = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices = gebaeudebereich_auswahl, label="Gebäudebereich")

    entries = CSV5.objects.values_list('gebaeudenummer', flat=True).distinct()
    gebaeudenummer_auswahl = [(e, e) for e in entries]
    gebaeudenummer = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=gebaeudenummer_auswahl, label="Gebäudenummer")

    entries = CSV5.objects.values_list('ebene', flat=True).distinct()
    ebene_auswahl = [(e, e) for e in entries]
    ebene = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=ebene_auswahl)

    entries = CSV5.objects.values_list('raum', flat=True).distinct()
    raum_auswahl = [(e, e) for e in entries]
    raum = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=raum_auswahl)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because I use a dropwdown filter and when I updated a value from '25' to let's say '22' the dropdown filter still displays '25' until I manually restart the server.

Comment: Then *that* is the problem you need to fix. (This is a prime example of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).) You are certainly doing something wrong in that form; please post the form code.

Comment: updated. I don' t think there is anything wrong with my form because when I filter without selecting anything (displays all), the new value is there just not in the dropwdown.

Comment: Well, the problem is exactly with your filter, because you are doing queries at class level which you must never do. But this is a strange way to build a filter; what are you passing in when you instantiate it? The whole point is that the filter creates a set of dropdowns based on the values in the queryset you give it, you shouldn't need to specify the options manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms and the values that appear in dropdowns are only instantiated when the server starts. You probably don't want to restart `runserver`, as this won't be occurring with a production webserver.

Instead, you'll want to override the `__init__` method of the form, and set the values for the dropdown there. Here's a quick example:

```
class MyForm(forms.form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["my_field"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=MyModel.objects.all(),
        )
```

Good luck!